# Is "Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Sixth Edition" by Elliott Mendelson suitable for a beginning self learner?

Tags: reference-request, logic

Let me explain my math background first.
I recently finished "how to prove it" by velleman at home. That's it.

I stumbled upon "Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Sixth Edition" by Elliott Mendelson as a prerequisite for ordinal logic that alan turing helped pioneer.

Many amazon reviews on the fifth and sixth editions say it's not for self learners who are not familiar with logic already.

I'm starting to consider "An Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Richard E. Hodel.

Can anyone give a good recommendation for my self-study material?

Comment: You would need to indicate what you mean by "beginning". Mendelson's book is fine for a learner who understands the methods of mathematics (we call this "mathematical maturity"), even if the learner doesn't know any mathematical logic. The book is well written and rigorous, and will demand the same effort and attention as any other advanced mathematics book. If you don't have exposure to advanced mathematics and proof, or if you are looking for a light read on the beach, then the book is probably not for you. As the the Amazon reviews, I wouldn't give them any weight at all.

Comment: @CarlMummert Did "how to prove it 2nd edition" by velleman prepare me for Mendelson's book? I studied velleman's book from the beginning to the end although I solved only 5-6 exercises per chapter.

Comment: If you have that background, but haven't done anything else in advanced math, you are in a position where you could work through Mendelson's book, but if it is the first advanced book you have worked through you will find that it takes time, that the information is presented in a compact way, and that you have to stop and think frequently. This is absolutely normal for advanced math books - it just takes some experience to acclimate yourself to the way that mathematics is presented. I would recommend also looking at Enderton's book to see if you find it more readable.

Comment: My experience with the _fourth_ edition of Mendelson was that the part about logic is perfectly serviceable (with the caveats Carl mentions), the development of set theory is quite dense and can be heavy going, and for the love of Turing don't plan to learn computability theory from it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Why does it teach the set theory? Does it serve as a comprehensive introduction to set theory? I'm currently reading "the annotated turing". I'm going to read "the essential turing" after I finish learning "the annotated turing" and ordinal logic. Does the annotated turing or the essential turing teach computability in any meaningful way? If they don't, which book do you recommend?

Comment: @crocket: Yes, there's a development of the standard topics in axiomatic set theory there. I'm not privy to the author's thoughts, but formal logic _plus_ an axiomatic treatment of arithmetic _plus_ axiomatic set theory _plus_ some recursion (or computability) theory together constitute the basics of what one needs to know in order to follow arguments about the foundations of mathematics, and it looks like the author set out to present those basics. I don't know those other books you refer to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Why do you think "Introduction to Mathematical Logic, Sixth Edition" by Elliott Mendelson is not a good book to learn computability from? If it is not a good book for computability, which book do you recommend?

Comment: Peter Smith has a very thorough summary of introductory logic books at http://logicmatters.net/students/tyl/ . For computability, Cutland's book is often used for undergraduate courses, but I feel it is too light. Enderton's computability book is has a very contemporary viewpoint, and I would recommend it. There is a nice, short book by Rebecca Weber that is slightly more advanced, but gives a better sense of how a computability theorist would think about the area.

Comment: As for this question, I suspect it has been asked before. If so, it may end up being closed as a duplicate. But the search feature on the site makes it hard to find older questions, so maybe nobody will find the question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: No. Because of its variation of Generalization rule. (It will mess with your intuitions, cause headache etc., without any good compensation.)
 
For beginners the books where Gen is of form "if there's proof |- P(x), then there's proof |- forall x, P(x)" are much much better.